# Critique: how do I improve the typography of this user interface?

Tags: typography, critique, interface-design

I'm new to designing interfaces as my focus was mainly on icons. I would like to know how I could improve the typography experience on the design below. Mainly the heading and the paragraph.

[image]

Comment: What aspect would you want to improve, and why? As-is, your question is a bit too broad--we prefer concise questions that have an objectively 'right' answer. If you could name aspects that you'd like to work on, that'd be great!

Comment: I would like the header and paragraph to be improved in a sense that'll not look out of order and also wan't to know if there's any room for improvements .

Comment: How are they out of order? Looks fine to me ...

Comment: @MuhammadOmarNaveed please edit your question to include more detail about your goal.

Comment: Given the nature of your problem, could you include full context. Or is this full context? It does look off to me, and I do know why, but I'm not sure if its relevant because this might only be part of the product.

Comment: Downvoted as the question doesn't have an intent for a straightforward answer but rather is invites discussion.

Answer (score 1):

For the headline I would suggest [Bitter Bold](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Bitter). I think that the headline could use a thick, serifed font for contrast with the body copy. Bitter got some pretty nice hard serifs so - in my opinion - it goes excellent with sans-serif paragraphs.